# Sum datetime64[ns] Column and float64 Column

Tags: python, time, sum

I'm trying to sum two columns: One is format float64 which are seconds and the other is format datetime64[ns]. They look like:

```
 time                  | float
---------------------------------
 2020-07-28 14:53:10   | 5.0
 2021-08-30 15:28:52   | 68.0
 2019-04-25 14:55:36   | 49.0
 2020-03-24 09:19:45   | 8.0
 2021-02-10 07:44:26   | 6.0
```

I performed the sum as follows:

```
df['time'] + df['float']
```

I then received the following message:

> ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')

I tried to convert the float column to timedate and then perform the sum and I received the following message:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'`

Comment: What are you trying to add? Is the float column seconds, days, years?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the "float" column to `pd.Timedelta` using [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then `sum`:

```
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
df["float"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["float"], unit="D") #change units if needed

>>> df.sum(axis=1)
0   2020-08-02 14:53:10
1   2021-11-06 15:28:52
2   2019-06-13 14:55:36
3   2020-04-01 09:19:45
4   2021-02-16 07:44:26
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), change your unit as appropriate.

```py
df.float = df.float.apply(functools.partial(pd.Timedelta, unit='seconds'))
```